Powershell output to table format
Need some help in getting output for the below code as table format, below is the code used.
$URLList = Get-Content  C:\temp\link.txt



$result = foreach ($uri in $URLList)  { 
    try{
        $res =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -Method Head -TimeoutSec 5 -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = [int]$res.StatusCode  
      
       
        
        
    } 
    catch {
        $status = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }
    # output a formatted string to capture in variable $result
    " URL- $uri - Status- $status " 
}  

#print
$result

Currently result received as below
URL- http://example.com - Status- 200 

Need it as below in table format,
| URL                  | Status |

| http://example.com   |200     |

" When the output is send via email i am getting as below,
enter image description here
Expected email output like this expected output via email

Format-Table?

Just change " URL- $uri - Status- $status " into [PsCustomObject]@{URL = $uri; Status = $status} and then output at the end with $result | Format-Table -AutoSize. Original code here

Helo @Theo, - it worked with the correct headers but it doenst have a table format, with rows and columns, can you please help with that ? i trying to output this to an email report

What do you mean by but it doenst have a table format ? If you output an object inside the loop as I have commented, then $result will be an array of objects with two properties: URL and Status. If you then print with $result | Format-Table -AutoSize  you will get a table in the console output. If you want to capture that as formatted table (text) for use in an email, do $tableText = $result | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String

HI Theo, i am trying to get output in rows and column in an email , currently even using $tabletext it is not in a correct format.

You'd better [edit] your question then and show us what you consider correct format

UPDATE 2: added code to send by email
UPDATE: added code to show a "pretty" table of the results.
This work for a one-time simple thing, but for better management of formatting outputs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.4
Original:
Do not output a string, but a PSCustomObject.
You can then pipe it to Format-Table (which is often unnecessary as Powershell often uses it automatically for PSCustomObjects but it does not hurt to force it)
$result = foreach ($uri in $URLList) { 
    Write-Verbose 1
    try {
        $res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -Method Head -TimeoutSec 5 -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = [int]$res.StatusCode  
    } 
    catch {
        $status = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        URL    = $uri
        Status = $status
    }
}  

# convert to HTML, add CSS to add visible borders, then cast to a single string
[string]$Body = $result | ConvertTo-Html | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<(td|th)>', '<$1 style="border: 1px solid black">' }    

# added -BodyAsHtml to tell the system it's not pure text.
send-mailmessage -to "example@exapmple.com" -from "example1@example.com" -subject "URL/API's Status Alert" -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMPTServer -Port $port -UseSsl -Credential $credential 


Yep, that's what I already commented, but apparently this is still not the correct format. I've asked the OP to elaborate

@Theo updated with what OP wants

Let's hope so.. ;)

@Theo and sirtao -  thanks for helping out, the format when outputting in powershell console is fine,but when send via email the format is gone and no rows or columns available, i will try to attach picture in the thread for your convenience

How are you passing the results to the email?

@Mil You should have made that clear in the first place.. What you need is the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet where you can create a html body containing your table with the style you want it to have.
I suggest you search for examples here on SO, but to give you a headstart, see here or here or ...

@sirtao- i am using this to pass
send-mailmessage -to "example@exapmple.com" -from "example1@example.com" -subject "URL/API's Status Alert" -Body $($result | Out-String  )  -SmtpServer $SMPTServer -Port $port -UseSsl -Credential $credential

@Theo- Sorry for the confusion and trouble as i am a  beginner i thought while outputting console will have the same result while sending it through email, let me go through the links you have mentioned and appreciate the help

sending it by email makes the portrayal much easier lol. Fixed the code.
